# Sort an ArrayList of HashMaps in Velocity

Tags: java, velocity

In a Velocity template, I have an arraylist of hashmaps.

Code sample:

```
#set($users = $userTool.getUsers())
##$users is an arraylist (java.util.ArrayList), each item a Hashmap (java.util.HashMap)
```

I'm struggling to do some sort in this array based on the value of a certain key from each Hash.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve this using the SortTool from VelocityTools

https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/SortTool.html

Will keep the question & answer to help others.